# _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHEAD->nBlockUse) error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to C++ (I'm most comfortable with node.js and Java, but have done some Python before) and am working through understanding pointers.  The following example generates a runtime error when compiled with debug symbols.

```
#include <iostream>

void main(){
    int number = 0;
    int * numberPtr = &number;
    * numberPtr = 1;

    std::cout << number;
    delete numberPtr;
}
```

And the error message:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\path\to\executable\main.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgdel.cpp

Expression: _BLOCK-TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)
```

FWIW, I've gotten the same error when I've compiled with both VS 2008 and 2013.

Comment: You're deleting an object you didn't dynamically allocate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Oli Charlesworth said, u did not dynamically allocate `numberPtr`, therefore you can't `delete` it. I suggest reading about `new` and `delete` and Dynamic Memory Allocation if you intend on coding in `C++`.

Comment: I suggest you don't. There are better alternatives, such as `std::string` and `std::unique_ptr<>`